# How to add interval of weeks using PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know that I can add interval like:

```
Select current_date + interval '4 weeks'
```

My issue is that the 4 isn't constant but a value from column.

so in my case I have this situation:

```
 id   requestdate   lt_weeks
  1    2016-06-01      5
  2    2016-06-12      4
  3    2016-06-12     NULL
  4    2016-06-12      4
```

I need to do requestdate  + interval of lt_weeks value.

i can't find the proper syntax for such operation.

The query

```
select requestdate  + interval lt_weeks 'weeks'
from table_1
```

doesn't work it says syntax error near lt_weeks

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply:

```
Select current_date + coalesce(lt_weeks, 0) * interval '1 week'
```

An "interval" is a bona fide data type in Postgres, so you can use arithmetic on it.

Comment: how will it work when lt_weeks  is null? I will put it as coalesce(lt_weeks ,0) but i'm not sure it will do what i expect it to do and leave the date as is.

Comment: @Johnathan . . . The original formulation would have returned `NULL`, but a `coalesce()` easily fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you've outlined works only for string constants.

Try this:

```
SELECT requestdate, requestdate + (lt_weeks||' weeks')::interval
  FROM table_1;
```